# flutter go_router and riverpod Get parameters send to Controller

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-go-router

flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.7

go_router: ^10.1.0

flutter 3.13.0

code:
go_router：`context.pushNamed("/home",queryParameters: {"arguments": user.name});`

ControllerCode:

`

```
    final ControllerProvider =
        StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<Controller, State>((ref) => Controller());

    class State {}

    class Controller extends StateNotifier<State> {
      Controller() : super(State()) {
        //How should I obtain it correctly arguments ???
        if (arguments != null) {
          state.textEditingController.text = Get.arguments;
          getData(page: 1, keyword: Get.arguments);
        } else {
          getData(page: 1);
        }
      }
    }
```

`

pageCode:

```
      class Page extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
        const Page({super.key});

        @override
        _State createState() => _State();
      }

      class _State extends ConsumerState<Page> {
        late State state;
        late Controller controller;

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final routeState = GoRouterState.of(context);
          if (routeState.uri.queryParameters["arguments"] != null) {
            routeState.uri.queryParameters["arguments"]!;
            //print username01
          }

          state = ref.watch(ControllerProvider);
          controller = ref.watch(ControllerProvider.notifier);
          return Container();
        }
      }
```

How should I obtain it correctly arguments to `Controller(arguments)`  ?

`ControllerProvider` Can be obtained `GoRouterState.of(context)` to Controller?

Controller get GoRouterState.of(context).uri.queryParameters